# Will the Soekris vpn1401 AES/VPN accelerator card work with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu 16.04LTS server which doubles as a VPN router/gateway for my LAN. I've just moved to a fast broadband service and have run into the limitations of the Atom D525 CPU - maximum VPN throughput is about 45Mbit/s.

I'm thinking of experimenting with hardware acceleration to see if I can improve VPN throughput. I found a Soekris VPN1401 PCI card on Ebay, but having trouble finding out if it works with Linux (I know it is supported by OpenVPN).

Can you help, or perhaps suggest an alternative that does work?

Comment: Did you already see this page http://wiki.soekris.info/Vpn14x1 (Last edited 2009) and this ? https://soekris.com/vpn-1401.html -> support.

Comment: Yes, I saw both those. It apparently works very well with FreeBSD, and there are rumours of people using it with "Linux" but nothing for Ubuntu specifically.

It is cheap enough for me to give it a punt and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I obtained the card in question, and installed it in my server system.  It booted up without issues and the card was identified correctly (lspci).

No drivers were loaded, but having the card in my possession allowed me to identify what driver would be needed. I'm apparently looking for hifn_795x.ko which doesn't exist in the current kernel. It looks like the driver is no longer maintained in the Ubuntu kernel, potentially because of an incompatibility with AMD64 code (see launchpad bug)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1085115

There is evidence that the Fedora 32bit kernels still have the module available.

https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kmod(hifn_795x.ko)

Not much good to me though. The most likely scenario is that I'll keep the card and use in a home-built pfSense router at some time in the future.

Comment: Could also be a good opportunity to get familiar with the *BSD family of OSes; you could be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Actually, it would be a return to *BSD for me, but yes, agreed.